# Extracting a specific digit from an integer

Tags: java

I'm rather sure I haven't found an answer to this because I'm not sure of the correct term for what I'm trying to do, so apologies in advance if it's very straight forward/well documented.

I have a set of numbers which I need to output a number in a specific position (hundreds), IE:
For 1302, I need to output 3
For 1802, I need to output 8

etc

How can I accomplish this with Java?

I should note that this is easy with 100's ( / 100), however I can't seem to figure out how to do this when the number is > 100.

Comment: Are the strings always the same lenght and format?

Comment: if the number is < 100 then just print a 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep the number,

```
(num / 100) % 10
```

should generally work.

Comment: Huzah - that was it. Forgot about the modulus. I think doing an if int >= 1000 then %1000 / 100 should work just fine.

Thank you sir :)

Comment: @Numpty Consider accepting that answer if it resolved your problem.

Comment: Yep - when the time hits he'll get it :)

Answer (score 3):

a easy way is use % (modulo) and then /

like :

(input % 1000) / 100

**Edit** It works if you use only int number.

Comment: You should mention you need to keep the result as an int (otherwise you'll get 3.08 for instance)

Comment: @Truth  I agree. (I didn't mention it because the OP was using int only) , I edit my answer

Answer (score 2):

If you want to output the second number of your number you could convert it to a String and then use the `substring` method ([doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29)) to get the character you want. (of course it only works if the number you want is always located at the same position).

Answer (score 1):

An example of one solution, to get you on your way :)

```
    int i = 1302;
    String hundreds = Integer.toString(i).substring(1, 2);
    System.out.println(hundreds);
```

Comment: Why? Why convert it to a string when it can be solved easily with just numbers?!

Comment: "But you should note there are more efficient ways of solving your problem" Would be appropriate.

Comment: Stack Overflow is so hostile at times

Comment: I'm not hostile (you haven't been downvoted, have you?) I'm merely stating that when dealing with inexperienced programmers, it's best to teach them the correct way, rather than the way THEY think is the correct way.